# Batch Requests and attached files with PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, batch-file

I'm trying to make a batch request to post an unique photo on differents page.

For that, I wish to use **Batch Post Requests** to optimize the proccess.

**My Code :**

```
    $facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' => myappId, secret => mysecret, 'cookie' => true, 'fileUpload' => true, 'domain' => $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']));

    $request[0] = array( 
        'relative_url' => 'facebookPageId1/photos'
        'method' => 'post' 
        'body' => 'access_token=page_access_token_1&message=my_message&attached_files=' . basename($picture));

    $request[1] = array(
      'relative_url' =>'facebookPageId2/photos'
      'method' => 'post'
      'body' => 'access_token=page_access_token_2&message=my_message&attached_files=' . basename($picture));

    $file[basename($picture)] = '@' . realpath($picture);
    $batch = json_encode(array_values(requests));
    $params = array('batch' => $batch);
    $params = array_merge($params, $file);

    $facebook->api('/', 'POST', $params)
```

Now when I am running this code I got the following output for my two requests :

```
'{"error":{"message":"(#324) Requires upload file","type":"OAuthException","code":324}}'
```

So what's the problem ?

I set **fileUpload** at true on my Facebook Object and I tried to post a photo on the url "*pageId/photos*" with a classic request and it's worked perfectly. But witch a batch request, I have always the same error.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT :** Ok I get my mistake, my requests was wrong :

```
$request[0] = array( 
    'relative_url' => 'facebookPageId1/photos',
    'method' => 'post',
    'body' => 'access_token=page_access_token_1&message=my_message',
    'attached_files' => basename($picture)
);

$request[1] = array(
  'relative_url' =>'facebookPageId2/photos',
  'method' => 'post',
  'body' => 'access_token=page_access_token_2&message=my_message',
  'attached_files' => basename($picture)
);
```

But now I got the following error :

```
{"error":{"message":"File picturename.jpg has not been attached","type":"GraphBatchException"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i do:

```
$files['access_token']=$access_token;
$request[0] = array( 
    'relative_url' => 'facebookPageId1/photos',
    'method' => 'POST',
    'body' => 'message=my_message',
    'attached_files' => 'file_0'
);
$files['file_0']= basename($picture);

$batchresult = $facebook->api("/?batch=".urlencode(json_encode($request)), 'POST', $files);
```

Facebook Batch ask you to put the files in diferent arrays, also you can put the access token in there, and you need to put it once.